# Fill convex area between 3D points in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a collection of 3D points in Matlab

```
PY=0.5000         0    0.5000;
   0.5000    0.1250    0.3750;
   0.5000    0.2500    0.2500;
   0.5000    0.3750    0.1250;
   0.6250         0    0.3750;
   0.6250    0.1250    0.2500;
   0.6250    0.2500    0.1250;
   0.6250    0.3750         0;
   0.7500         0    0.2500;
   0.7500    0.1250    0.1250;
   0.7500    0.2500         0];
```

These points are parts of the unit simplex

```
close all
patch([0 0 1],[0 1 0],[1 0 0],[0.8 0.8 0.8]);
axis equal 
axis([0 1 0 1 0 1])
view(120,30)
 hold on
scatter3(PY(:,1), PY(:,2), PY(:,3))
```

**Question:** I would like to fill the convex region that one gets by connecting these points. I'm unable to do that. Could you help?

This is what I tried

**1)** `CHPY=convhull(PY(:,1),PY(:,2),PY(:,3) );`

which gives me as error

```
Error computing the convex hull. The points may be coplanar or collinear.
```

**2)**

```
T = delaunayTriangulation(PY);
       K = convexHull(T);
```

which gives me as error

```
Error using delaunayTriangulation/convexHull
The triangulation is empty.
```

Comment: [This MATLAB Answers Q&A](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/352830-convhull-convhulln-data-is-coplanar-data-is-degenerate-in-at-least-one-dimension-i-know-it-is-but) should be your solution. Tested that on your dataset, and seems to be correct to me.

Comment: It works, thanks, that was very useful.